# django-lfs product template

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-lfs

i'm quite new to django-lfs.

I've been playing with the code trying to build a shop that fix my needs.
I've have run into an issue that i'm not able to fix.

I need to access , from the product view (catalog/product/inline) to the category from where i have access this page.
I can see it if y display the breadcrumbs.
   example : Home > category 1 > product 1
but i'm not able to access the "category" object so i can use it's data.

Is there anybody who can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've manage this using creating a template tag that generates my on menu. <br> Not  excaly what i wanted initially...<br> <dode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've manage this adding a template tag...
Not exacly what i wanted..but works fine.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('tagging/lateral_menu.html', takes_context=True)
def lateral_menu(context):  
    object = context.get("category") or context.get("product")

if object.__class__.__name__.lower() == "product":
    request = context.get("request")
    category=lfs.catalog.utils.get_current_product_category(request, object)
else:
    category = object

top_category=category
while top_category.parent is not None:
    top_category = category.parent

categories =top_category.get_all_children()
return {"category" :category, "top_category" : top_category, "categories" : categories }
```

Then in the template i can obtain al the data i need.